# Dispay Content when Page fully loaded

Tags: php

I am Fetching tweets and showing then in my site within bjqs slider .. i put limit on tweets , now when i open the url of mysite it show all tweets,i want to show tweets when page is fully loaded.
is there any way to show any div only when page is fully loaded. without using js

Comment: Whats wrong with javascript?

Comment: How are you supposed to determine if things are loaded without the client side telling you it is loaded?

Comment: ha ha i wanted to know. if it is possible without using script .. i have the solution with js but if it's possible only with php it would be appreciated

Comment: PHP is server-side scripting language, which means it runs before it gets to the client.

Comment: Here is a diagram illustrating the difference between client-side and server-side scripting: http://www-scf.usc.edu/~chen681/itp104/client_diagram.gif

Answer (score 0):

Page is loading from top to bottom. And if you will set the div with tweets at the end of your page - it will be loading at least

Answer (score 0):

### Quick Solution

To hide a div until the entire html page has been downloaded, you can hide it in some CSS in an inline  tag at the top of the page, and show it in css at the bottom of the page (after all of the other markup, before the  tag.)

**This may or may not be what you mean by "fully loaded" (see below)**

### Fully Loaded (a long description)

A page is "fully loaded" when the html file, css, javascript, images and any other media have all finished loading.

The html file is a single file, and is the first to be downloaded by the browser. The browser immediately starts building this into a DOM tree and starts laying out and rendering the content immediately - often before the html file has finished downloading.

If the browser meets any javascript (inline or external), it pauses the rendering process and downloads, parses and executes the javascript, before continuing (this can often cause a visible pause).

Once the html file has finished downloading, the browser starts fetching the images and other included files.

During this whole process, the rendering engine is constantly updating the visible webpage and many javascript events are being fired (which can lead to changes in the DOM, re-renders, etc).

As soon as this has "settled down", once the last file has been downloaded and the last chain of loading events and handlers have been executed, the document is **ready** (another event).

The javascript may continue initiate more downloads via AJAX or by adding elements such as images and scripts to the DOM (which require the browser to download the linked files), but all of the files which were **STATICALLY** linked in the HTML code have been downloaded.

This is what most people mean by "fully loaded".

If this is what you mean, then the only way to detect that is by catching the "document ready" event, using Javascript.